# Unity3D Code repeats too much

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to make if you got enough gold then comes you need rock, if you got enough rock then you need enough gold, but if you have both then you can "Upgrade". But if you got both then it goes back to the you need gold.

```
    void Update()
    {
        if(enoughgold == true & enoughrocks == true)
        {
            Upgrade.text = "Upgrade to 2014!";
        }

        if(sellrocks.gold > 9999)
        {
            enoughgold = true;
        }
        else
        {
            enoughgold = false;
        }

        if(click.rock > 2999)
        {
            enoughrocks = true;
        }
        else
        {
            enoughrocks = false;
        }

        if(enoughgold == true)
        {
            Upgrade.text = "You need 3,000 Rocks!";
        }
        else
        {
            Upgrade.text = "You need 10,000 Gold!";
        }

        if (enoughrocks == true)
        {
            Upgrade.text = "You need 10,000 Gold!";
        }
        else
        {
            Upgrade.text = "You need 3,000 Rocks!";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this? You first see whether the user has enough gold and rocks and then do the checking.
I have simplified `if (enoughgold == true)` to `if (enoughgold)` as the `== true` is redundant.

```
void Update()
{
    enoughgold = sellrocks.gold > 9999;
    enoughrocks = click.rock > 2999;

    if (enoughgold && enoughrocks)
        Upgrade.text = "Upgrade to 2014!";
    else if (enoughgold && !enoughrocks)
        Upgrade.text = "You need 3,000 Rocks!";
    else if (!enoughgold && enoughrocks)
        Upgrade.text = "You need 10,000 Gold!";
    else if (!enoughgold && !enoughrocks)
        Upgrade.text = "You need 10,000 Gold and 3,000 Rocks!";
}
```

You could also create an enum to handle all 4 possibilities: if the user has only enough rocks, if the user has only enough gold, if the user has enough of both and if the user doesn't have enough of any.